# Update globale variable inside a function called by addEventListener

Tags: javascript, scope

I try to update a globale variable with a mousemove event but it doesn't work. I don't know what more I can do.

I tried to create a variable for my function to reuse this but no results again.

My code :

```
let delta = 0;

window.addEventListener('mousemove', updateDelta, false);

function updateDelta() {
   delta++;
}

console.log(delta);
```

So when I move the cursor, delta is not updated outside the function.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes it is, why do you figure it isn't? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/79e4nzvp/ Wait, when do you expect that `console.log()` to run?

Comment: You need console.log inside update delta function

Answer (score 0):

this code works fine, but the problem is you have console.log right after that function which means that console log is triggered immidietly after you run it.

You can use developer tools in google chrome and add breakpoint for it so you will see it works.

Also you can put that console log in the function and you will se its update.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to update a global variable with a mousemove event but it
>   doesn't work.

The problem is not in the scope.

It is in the `console.log` is called immediately after the function is run, so it only shows the initial value.
You can try the below method calling a function to print

```js
var delta = 0;
window.addEventListener('mousemove', updateDelta, false);

function updateDelta() {
   delta++;  
   print()
}
function print(){
console.log(delta);}
```

**OR**

as stated in comments and other answers you can print the value just after increment.

```js
var delta = 0;
window.addEventListener('mousemove', updateDelta, false);

function updateDelta() {
   delta++;  
  console.log(delta);
}
```

Both will work fine for you.